# two-way binding in directive, model from service non-assignable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I am getting the following error: "Expression '{0}' used with directive '{1}' is non-assignable!", as can be shown here: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nonassign

Edit: Having moved the config object into the scope this part is resolved, however the models are still not bound as expected. http://plnkr.co/edit/AVs2IW75oWavpsPNDgnb?p=preview

Old plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/AVs2IW75oWavpsPNDgnb?p=preview
(Try and edit a field and check the console)

I don't really understand the problem which is why that link can't help me to solve it. I am using a directive to bind data, and the data that is being "bound" is actually pointing to a service.

```
<multi-edit model="profileService.current" config="{
    title: 'Edit profile description', 
    fields: [
    {name: 'Title', model: profileService.current.title, input: true}, 
    {name: 'Description', model: profileService.current.description, textarea: true}
]}">
  CLick me
</multi-edit>
```

So I am trying to edit profileService.current.title for example, by using the ng-model config.fields[0].model. It can read the data correctly, but not write to it. What do I need to do in order to be able to write to the correct models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

You should use a scope model for "config".

Put this in your main controller:

```
$scope.config = {
  title: 'Edit profile description',
  fields: [{
    name: 'Title',
    model: 'title',
    input: true
  }, {
    name: 'Description',
    model: 'description',
    textarea: true
  }]
};
```

and then in your main HTML:

```
<multi-edit model="profileService.current" config="config">
  CLick me
</multi-edit>
```

Then, in your directive HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in config.fields">
    <input ng-if="value.input" type="text" ng-model="model[config.fields[key].model]" />
    <textarea ng-if="value.textarea" type="text" ng-model="model[config.fields[key].model]"></textarea>
</li>
```

See the updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GLq9cyrLGtUCOncSfgEU?p=preview).

Comment: Duh! I only put it like this in order to test if it even would work, thinking of moving it to the controller post testing. So you solved the problem, however the editor ng-model doesn't reflect the original ng-model as can be observed here: http://plnkr.co/edit/AVs2IW75oWavpsPNDgnb?p=preview

So I guess this only solved the first problem (and thank you!).

Comment: Because `profileService.current` is not updated in your directive's controller; but `model` fields of `scopeConf.fields` is updated. Try `<pre>model from bind data: {{ scopeConf.fields[1].model }}</pre>` in your index.html and you will see the data will change.

Comment: So is there a way to make sure that profileService.current binds correctly to the conf/directive?

Comment: You may use the `model` object, which is two-way binded to `profileService.current`, in your directive. Please see my update to the answer; I forked yor plunker.

Comment: The problem is that I am now locked into using model.title and model.description. Another object might not have a description, and instead just be filled with other data. I am trying to generalize as much as possible to be able to reuse the directive with different types of data, which is the reason for the config ability.

Comment: I solved this last problem. Maybe you can update your answer and I'll mark it as resolved? http://plnkr.co/edit/GLq9cyrLGtUCOncSfgEU?p=preview

Have a look at the config.fields.model in app.js, and the ng-repeat in dir.html. Also added the "Discard changes" on close button.

Comment: Updated my answer with your final solution. It's been a nice team work. :)